# Mockito InvocationTargetException on mocking a method

Tags: java, mockito

Here's the code that I'm trying to debug through on Intellij and I see that it causes  the InvocationTargetException on encountering the when-ThenReturn inside test1() method.

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Thing {

    Thing() {}

    ThingGrandParent tgp;

    public int fun(int size) {
        int r = tgp.GpFun(size);
        return r;
    }
}

public class ThingGrandParent {

    public int GpFun(int y) {
        return GpFun2();
    }

    public int GpFun2() {
        return 1;
    }
}

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockIgnore("javax.management.*")
@PrepareForTest({Thing.class})
public class ThingTest {

    @Mock
    ThingGrandParent tgpp;

    @InjectMocks
    Thing t;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {
        when(tgpp.GpFun2()).thenReturn(-5); // this causes the InvocationTargetException
        assertEquals(-5, t.fun(4));
    }
}
```

It gives: **java.lang.AssertionError:
Expected :-5
Actual   :0**

Why isn't it able to mock the **GpFun2()** method?

Comment: `tgpp` is a mock, which means it doesn't have `GpFun()` defined, so `GpFun2()` never gets called.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem But I can mock GpFun() like - `when(tgpp.GpFun(anyInt())).thenReturn(-5);`, why so?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.  But in your example, you only stubbed `GpFun2()`.  And `GpFun2()` never gets called, in your test, so it makes no difference whether you stub it or not.